# Search a series for a word. Return that word and N others in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, lambda

Okay, I need help.   I created a function to search a string for a specific word. If the function finds the `search_word` it will return the word the and N words that precede it. The function works fine with my test strings but I cannot figure out how to apply the function to an entire series?

**My goal** is to create a new column in the data frame that contains the `n_words_prior` whenever the `search_word` exists.

```
n_words_prior = []
test = "New School District, Dale County"

def n_before_string(string, search_word, N):
    global n_words_prior 
    n_words_prior = []
    found_word = string.find(search_word)
    if found_word == -1: return ""
    sentence= string[0:found_word]
    n_words_prior = sentence.split()[N:]
    n_words_prior.append(search_word)
    return n_words_prior
```

The **current dataframe** looks like this:

```
data = [['Alabama', 'New School District, Dale County'], 
        ['Alaska', 'Matanuska-Susitna Borough'], 
        ['Arizona', 'Pima County - Tuscon Unified School District']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['State', 'Place'])
```

The improved function would take the inputs `'Place'`,`'County'`,`-1` and create the following result.

```
improved_function(column, search_word, N)

new_data = [['Alabama', 'New School District, Dale County','Dale County'], 
        ['Alaska', 'Matanuska-Susitna Borough', ''], 
        ['Arizona', 'Pima County - Tuscon Unified School District','Pima County']]
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['State', 'Place','Result'])
```

I thought embedding this function would help, but it has only made things more confusing.

```
def fast_add(place, search_word):
    df[search_word] = df[Place].str.contains(search_word).apply(lambda search_word: 1 if search_word == True else 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fun(sentence, search_word, n):
    """Return search_word and n preceding words from sentence."""
    words = sentence.split()
    for i,word in enumerate(words):
        if word == search_word:
            return ' '.join(words[i-n:i+1])
    return ''
```

Example:

```
df['Result'] = df.Place.apply(lambda x: fun(x, 'County', 1))
```

Result:

```
     State                                         Place       Result
0  Alabama              New School District, Dale County  Dale County
1   Alaska                     Matanuska-Susitna Borough             
2  Arizona  Pima County - Tuscon Unified School District  Pima County
```

Comment: Wow.  I can't believe it.  That's a huge help @Stef.

Comment: Glad to have helped. If this solved your question you may consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the link @Stef!  Now I know what to do in the future.  Using your code I was also able to figure out a solution for searching forward in a string as well.